# Lua source to executable using Luadist

Tags: lua, cmake

According to this page https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository/wiki/Example:-Lua-module , it is possible to create executable from Lua source file with Luadist. However, I am not clear how to do this. I have a Lua source file (named abcd.lua) with IUP GUI code that runs well with iuplua.exe . How can I convert this to an executable? It seems from above mentioned page that I need to create a file as follows:

```
project ( abelhas NONE )
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8 )

include ( cmake/dist.cmake )
include ( lua )

install_lua_executable ( abcd abcd.lua )
```

I believe I have to name above file as CMakeLists.txt and then run cmake command in the folder which contain this and the abcd.lua file. Is this correct? Can I use cmake-gui (cmake-qt-gui) for this? Is cmake a part of Luadist or do I have to install it separately? I cannot find any dist.cmake file in Luadist folder, though there is one cmake.lua file present. I will appreciate any explanation of this procedure since I have never used cmake before.

Comment: Are you trying to run lua embeded in a C or C++ application?

Comment: No. I want an standalone exe file for distribution.

Comment: I'll toss what I have up anyways. It might work for you.

Comment: Compiling a C program with lua embedded in it will create a standalone executable- so that could be a valid method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using `xxd.lua` for embedding my lua scripts in `C++` and `C` projects. `xxd.lua` generates a `C` file that holds a hexdump of a given file as an unsigned char array. From there the `C` file is compiled in with the rest of the program.

EmbLuaFiles.cmake:

```
file(DOWNLOAD https://github.com/gittup/tup/blob/master/src/luabuiltin/xxd.lua
     "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Path/To/Store/File/At"
     SHOW_PROGRESS
     EXPECTED_HASH hash_value)

macro(EmbedLuaFiles lua depends)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT LuaScriptBinding.c
           COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy
           "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/DevelopmentTools/xxd.lua" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
           COMMAND ${lua} xxd.lua LuaScript.lua LuaScriptBinding.c
           DEPENDS ${depends}
           WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
endmacro()
```

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(EmbedLuaFiles)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT lua.exe
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lua-build"
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lua-build/lua.exe"
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lua-src"
            )
set(LUA_C_FILES LuaScriptBinding.c)

EmbedLuaFiles(lua.exe "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lua.exe")
set(LUA_EXE lua.exe ${LUA_C_FILES})
add_executable(TargetProject ${SOURCE_FILES} ${LUA_EXE})
```

In `c / c++` these can be accessed with:

```
 #if DEBUG
    #define LUA_SCRIPT "LuaScript.lua"
    #define LUA_SCRIPT_LEN 0
 #else
    extern "C"
    {
        extern unsigned char LuaScript_lua[];
        extern unsigned int LUA_SCRIPT_LEN;
    };
    #define LUA_SCRIPT (char*)LuaScript_lua
    #define LUA_SCRIPT_LEN LUA_SCRIPT_LEN
 #endif

 void loadFile(lua_state *luaState, const char *luaFile, size_t len)
 {
    #if !DEBUG
       if(luaL_loadbuffer(luaState, luaFile, len, luaFile))
    #else
       if(luaL_loadfile(luaState, luaFile) != 0)
    #endif
          cerr << "Failed to load lua file" << endl;
 }
int main()
{
   luaState = LuaL_newstate();
   luaL_openlibs(luaState);
   loadFile(luaState, LUA_SCRIPT, LUA_SCRIPT_LEN);
   lua_call(luaState, 0, 0);
   // run the script
   lua_close(luaState);
}
```

If you're running virus protection you'll need to make sure to identify the directory you're running `xxd.lua` from as being exempt, or the `c` files won't be generated.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and well-explained answer. It will take me some time really understand it.